# Separate anovas or 7 way manova?

Tags: regression, anova, mean, spss, two-way

I have 7 independent variables and two dependent variables which I think I should run 7 way manova, but this method is to complicated to compute, is running separate anovas for each dependent variable a good method?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @ thanks bot ☹️

Comment: What is the hypothesis and the research objective. It is crucial to provide it if you want to get a proper answer.